# How do I create a custom Apache log (with just htaccess files) that logs filenames (and paths)?

Tags: apache, logs

I have 1and1 shared hosting (for better or worse) and Apache configuration is done via htaccess files - no access to configuration files is provided.

I want to create a custom log to log accesses to files, logging just the filenames, so that I can then, on a daily basis, go through that log and create a sitemap.xml file from it.

What Apache configuration is necessary to do this?

Comment: What did you try already? Have a look here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html and specifically the `CustomLog` directive to create a new format.

Comment: The CustomLog directive can't appear in .htaccess files - which is all I've got access to unfortunately.